# Pentaho breaks single group into multiple sub groups

Tags: pentaho

For some reason, Pentaho is breaking some of my groupings into many small sub-groups.

I have the report set to report all products and group by vendor, and in the group footer count the number of products per vendor. For some vendors (e.g. Vendor X), the report will come out like this:

> **Vendor X:**
>
> Product A
>
> Product B
>
> *Count: 2*
>
> **Vendor X:**
>
> Product C:
>
> *Count: 1*

Why is Pentaho breaking the groups into pieces? This is making the counts incorrect. Vendor is a parameter that the user can select, and Vendor X only appears once in the parameter list. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Thank you,

Monica

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that some instances of vendor names had white space after the name. Using TRIM() on the vendor_name parameter made everything end up in the same group.